# How scroll back in time in dynamic chart with achartengine

Tags: android, dynamic, charts, scroll, achartengine

I implemented a dynamic chart that plot data in real time sent by wifi from a microcontroller. I am trying to do scroll back in time, but i have no idea how to make that.
Can you help me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You first need to set the visible range this way:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(minValue);
renderer.setXAxisMax(maxValue);
```

Then, call repaint on the graphical view:

```
chartView.repaint();
```

Comment: What I mean is how can I view old data, doing scroll back in X axis. The idea is the data is plotting in real time and when the chart is touched twice by user, can scroll back in time. To do this I imagine that the data should be saved in a long bufer or file, but I don know how implement it while is plotting in real time. Excuse me by make the  question so open and no especific, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: The data is already added to the ACE dataset, so you just need to change the visible range to some older values.

Comment: Excuse me by my ignorance, but what is the ACE dataset?

Comment: The thing where you add data to such as AChartEngine (ACE) can display it.